# Hierarchy in SQL - display all elements under nodes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got two tables:

1. contain element_code and parent_node
2. contain relations between nodes on different levels

I want to see all the lowest elements under node on all levels.

I wrote something like this, as a result, I have got Child, Parent and indicator is it a LEAF.
So I can select the node and I will see all elements connected to this node. How to loop it to see not only elements on the selected level but everything under the node?

```
SELECT azienda_gerarchia_abbi.cod_azienda        AS CHILD, 
       azienda_gerarchia_abbi.cod_azienda_eleger AS PARENT, 
       azienda.desc_azienda0                     AS LABEL, 
       'X'                                       AS LEAF 
FROM   azienda_gerarchia_abbi 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN azienda 
                    ON azienda_gerarchia_abbi.cod_azienda = azienda.cod_azienda 
UNION 
SELECT cod_azienda_eleger       AS CHILD, 
       cod_azienda_eleger_padre AS PARENT, 
       desc_azienda_eleger0     AS LABEL, 
       NULL                     AS LEAF 
FROM   azienda_gerarchia
```

As the example:

[structure model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLPcN.png)

Levels are only for explanation. We do not store it in DB.

We have got Level 1 where we have got node 1 connected Element 1 and Element 2.

Under Node 1 We have got Node 3 - element 3 and element 4
and node 4 - element 5 and element 6

Additionally, under node 2, we have got node 3 with element 5 and 6

My query will return:

[result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NSSY.png)

So I can select each node eg NODE2 and I will see two elements and one node.

But as expected result, I would like to see all other levels, in my case Element 3,4,5,6 and Node4

```
In 1st table I have got:

>Element1 - Node1

>Element2 - Node1

>Element3 - Node2

>Element4 - Node2

>Element5 - Node3

>Element6 - Node3

>Element7 - Node4

>Element8 - Node4

In second:

>Node1-Node2

>Node1-Node3

>Node4-Node4
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  A db<>fiddle is also helpful.  And what does "level" mean?

Comment: I recommend looking into WITH RECURSIVE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Comment: Hello, can you precisely how it should be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

As Blue Star mentioned `WITH RECURSIVE` is likely the tool you need for this. It would be easier to create a great example if a sample set of data was provided as SQL. DBFiddle is a common tool for setting up test environments. Include `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements.

Here is what I've come up with to demonstrate a `RECURSIVE` query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS
(   -- base case for recursion
    SELECT aga.cod_azienda        AS CHILD 
         , aga.cod_azienda_eleger AS PARENT 
         , a.desc_azienda0        AS LABEL 
      FROM azienda_gerarchia_abbi aga
      LEFT JOIN azienda a ON aga.cod_azienda = a.cod_azienda 
     UNION ALL -- recurse through children
    SELECT aga.cod_azienda
         , aga.cod_azienda_eleger
         , a.desc_azienda0
      FROM t prev
      JOIN azienda_gerarchia_abbi nxt ON nxt.cod_azienda_eleger = prev.child
      LEFT JOIN azienda a2 ON nxt.cod_azienda = a2.cod_azienda 
) SELECT *
    FROM t
   WHERE t.child IS NULL -- You can adjust the WHERE clause here to get only the leaf nodes by whichever means works for you.
;
```